# Directory and image not saved in gallery

Tags: java, image, directory

```java
private void takeImage() {
        try{
            //openCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            //releaseCameraSource();
            //releaseCamera();
            //openCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
            //setUpCamera(camera);
            //Thread.sleep(1000);
            mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {

                private File imageFile;
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
                    try {
                        // convert byte array into bitmap
                        Bitmap loadedImage = null;
                        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
                        loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,
                                bytes.length);

                        // rotate Image
                        Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                        rotateMatrix.postRotate(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation());
                        rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,
                                loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),
                                rotateMatrix, false);
                        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        //File folder = null;

                        ////////////////


                        File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator +"MECFilters");
                        if (!directory.exists())
                            Toast.makeText(FaceFilterActivity.this,
                                    (directory.mkdirs() ? "Directory has been created" : "Directory not created"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(FaceFilterActivity.this, "Directory exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        ///////////
                        /*if (state.contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                            folder = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/faceFilter");
                        } else {
                            folder = new File(Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/faceFilter");
                        }
                        */
                        boolean success = true;
                        /*if (!directory.exists()) {
                            success = directory.mkdirs();
                        }*/
                        if (success) {
                            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                            imageFile = new File(directory.getAbsolutePath()
                                    + File.separator
                                    //+ new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString()
                                    + "Image.jpg");

                            imageFile.createNewFile();
                            
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }

                        ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        // save image into gallery
                        rotatedBitmap = resize(rotatedBitmap, 800, 600);
                        rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

                        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                        fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
                        fout.close();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                                imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK); //add this
                        finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception ex){
        }
 }
```

My directory is created Toast works but does not show in the files and image not saved in the gallery..please help thanks in advance

I also tried to ask for permission during runtime, it seems like the app has got the permission, therefore it cannot be the problem.

Some months ago I created another application and used identical code and the identical Sdk version, still it does not work with this one. I get "DIR not created successfully" and I do not know why, please help me figure out why I cannot create the directory.